# A question on diffeomorphims and their intuitive description

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I am relatively new to the concept of differential geometry and my approach is from a physics background (hoping to understand general relativity at a deeper level). I have read up on the notion of diffeomorphisms and I'm a little unsure on some of the concepts.

Suppose that one has a diffeomorphism $\phi : M\rightarrow M$ from a manifold onto itself, then a point $p\in M$ is mapped to a different point $p'\in M$ by $\phi$ as follows $$p\mapsto\phi (p)=p'$$
I get that in general these will then be two distinct points on the manifold, but I've heard diffeomorphisms are analogous to active coordinate transformations?! Is this because one can choose a coordinate chart $(U, \psi)$ in the neighbourhood of $p$, i.e. $p\in U\subset M$, such that the point $p$ has coordinate values $$\psi (p)=\lbrace x^{\mu}(p)\rbrace$$ and then map this point to a distinct point $p'$ via the diffeomorphism $\phi$. Having done so, can one then use a pullback mapping, $\phi^{\ast}$ to pullback the coordinates in the neighbourhood of $p'$, $\lbrace \tilde{x}^{\mu}(p')\rbrace$ to the coordinates $\lbrace x^{\mu}(p)\rbrace$ in the following manner $$ x^{\mu}(p)= (\phi^{\ast}\tilde{x})^{\mu}(p')$$ In this sense, is it that although $p$ and $p'$ are distinct points on the manifold, due to the diffeomorphism $\phi$ they can be assigned the same coordinate values?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are correct. Looking at wikipedia "an active transformation is a transformation which actually changes the physical position of a point", we see that the diffeomorphism $\phi$ is indeed an active transformation since the point $p$ is mapped to $\phi(p)$. It can be seen as a "chart transformation" since a chart $(U, \psi)$ around $p$ is mapped to a chart $(\phi(U), \psi \circ \phi^{-1})$ around $\phi(p)$ (this is just the inverse of your description).